Wrong values in generated columns in postgres 15.1
I have a problem with generated column in one of my tables. The column value is calculated basing on other column in the row (which is of type varchar). Most of the time it works fine. But sometimes the generated value is wrong - I can't find any specific steps that cause such issue. Simple non-updating update like 'update column=column where [[generated_column_value]]<>[[generated_column_expression]]' fixes the issue, but after some time the problem occurs again.
I tried recreate the column (drop it and create again), but it didn't help. Does any of you have similar problem or can you give me some recommendation, what should I check?
Following the alter that I used (the table has already column with name status of type varchar(1)):
alter table my_table 
add column is_active boolean generated always as (status = 'A') stored;

After some time, when I execute following select:
select *
from my_table
where is_active
  and status <> 'A'

I can receive some rows, but I expect no rows (as rows which have true in is_active column should all have value 'A' in column status). What can be the cause of the issue or what should I check?
Thanks a lot

Cannot reproduce: https://dbfiddle.uk/QhFPBXyq Please edit the fiddle and reproduce your issue.

PS. This can be a collation problem - i.e. the collations which are applied for generated column and for the query may differ.

Thank you for response @Akina. Unfortunately as I mentioned I don't have the steps, which causes the issue - it seems non-deterministic. For sure it happens after update of the status column. But sometimes it happens and in most cases not. Maybe it is connected with parallel DLMs on the table, but I tried this as well and also could not reproduce. Thanks for the tip with collation - maybe it is the problem - I try to change the data type for comparison. This problem is very strange and I cannot reproduce it locally. If you have any other tips, please let me know.
Thanks!

Thanks for the tip with collation - maybe it is the problem - I try to change the data type for comparison. The data type change won't help if this is a reason. Try to specify the collation to be applied explicitly in the generated column expression and/or in the query text.
